# HTML 5 w3c validation

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, w3c-validation

I validated my website using validator.w3.org

It reported the following error:

```
Line 5, Column 67: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
```

If I don't include that META tag, than all IE9 visitors will see my website in Quirks mode, and I want to prevent that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "IE9 visitors will see my website in Quirks mode"... are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes. Without that meta tag, default document mode is set to Quirks mode. I tested this on different computers.

Comment: I guess I need to read more because I thought it was "IE9" mode by default.

Comment: this is a duplicate,

please refer to:

[is-it-legal-to-use-ie-specific-metatags-in-html5][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977590/is-it-legal-to-use-ie-specific-metatags-in-html5

Comment: IE9 will use standards mode by default unless a comment is present before your DOCTYPE declaration, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529728/html5-doctype-putting-ie9-into-quirks-mode I can confirm that because I don't see my browser entering quirks mode with HTML5 doctype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always put the X-UA-Compatible setting into the actual HTTP headers instead. How you do that depends on the web server you are using, and what, if any, server-side framework you are using.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3. Could you please give me some code sample? Thanks!

Comment: @šljaker - I'm not familiar with ASP.NET MVC specifically, but in C# it's along the lines of `Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");`

Comment: You can add this to the web.config system.Webserver > httpProtocol > customHeaders section as well.

Answer (score 12):

Same problem here, but my solution is to add the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
```

Works great for me...

Answer (score 8):

You'll just have to accept the fact that if you want IE support, you'll need to give up perfect validation score.

It's alright though, `validity != quality`

Comment: you can set  <!--[if IE]> xua stuff  <![endif]--> this might preserve validity.

Comment: According to [this link](http://blog.yjl.im/2011/01/bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute.html), this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

For people using PHP, the way to pass this parameter through the header function in PHP:

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

Here is a a [post with code + explanation](http://www.joshuawinn.com/fix-html5-validator-error-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta/).

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple and theme can include this easy in feature templates
just open /templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/warp/systems/themes/head.php

from

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

to

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

**For guys using ASP.NET MVC**

One option is to use Action Filter on controllers/actions. This does slow down responses from the server a bit but I don't know the exact numbers. But it's a clean way to do it:

```
///
/// Represents an attribute that is used to add HTTP Headers to a Controller Action response.
///
public class HttpHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    ///
    /// Gets or sets the name of the HTTP Header.
    ///
    /// The name.
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ///
    /// Gets or sets the value of the HTTP Header.
    ///
    /// The value.
    public string Value { get; set; }

    ///
    /// Initializes a new instance of the  class.
    ///
    /// The name.
    /// The value.
    public HttpHeaderAttribute(string name, string value) {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.AllKeys.Contains(Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader(Name, Value);
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

However, the absolutely best and cleanest way for me is using `web.config`. Put this code into `<system.webServer>` element:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!-- 
                            http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/
                            Uncomment to serve cross-domain ajax requests

                            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                            -->
    <!-- 
                            Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
                            github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
                            Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk 
                            -->
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <!-- 
                            Allow cookies to be set from iframes (for IE only)
                            If needed, uncomment and specify a path or regex in the Location directive 

                            <add name="P3P" value="policyref=&quot;/w3c/p3p.xml&quot;, CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT&quot;" />
                            -->
    <!-- A little extra security (by obscurity) -->
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Obviously this only works in IIS7+.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried not giving a damn what HTML validators say about your code? That usually works for me.